# Why does the frame jump to the top of the view as I set "Horizontal centre in container" in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I don't remember this happening before, when I tried to set a horizontal centre constraint.

[image]

It also spews out a warning saying: Vertical position is ambiguous for label. Is that expected behavior? Setting a height constraint doesn't fix the problem. Am I doing something wrong or is Xcode tripping me up?

Comment: Do you have any vertical constraints on the label?  If not, then auto layout considers any vertical position acceptable, which means the vertical position is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to place your `UILabel` in the `UIViewController` you have to assign a vertical and horizontal position. In this way AutoLayout won't return any errors.

You have only specified the **x-axis position** (also called horizontal position). You may want to set the **vertical position** as well.

You can set the vertical position in two ways:

1. Center the `UILabel` vertically by selecting `Center Vertically In Container`;
2. Or create `Top Space to Top Layout Guide` or `Bottom Space to Bottom Layout Guide` constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set a height constraint, either set it a fixed distance from the top, or set it in the vertical center of the container.

Yes this is expected behaviour.